# C# Updating program based on a websites XML file

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I have a website which i am hosting a XML file on, the XML file as an example looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ProgramList>
<Program1>
    <version>1.0.0.0</version>
    <url>https://google.com/files/Program1.exe</url>
<Program1>

<Program2>
    <version>1.0.0.1</version>
    <url>https:google.com/files/Program2.exe</url>
<Program2>
</ProgramList>
```

I was able to download a new version using the webclient and xmlreader, i got this source off a website, it is not my own work: themech.net

here is the snippet i am using:

```
Version newVersion = null;

string url = "";
XmlTextReader reader;  
try  
{  
string xmlURL = "http://domain/app_version.xml";
reader = new XmlTextReader(xmlURL);

reader.MoveToContent();  

 string elementName = "";   
 if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) &&  
     (reader.Name == "Program1"))  
 {  
  while (reader.Read())  
  {  
   if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)  
    elementName = reader.Name;  
   else  
   {    
    if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text) &&  
        (reader.HasValue))  
    {  
     switch (elementName)  
     {  
     case "version":  
      newVersion = new Version(reader.Value);  
      break;  
     case "url":  
      url = reader.Value;  
      break;  
     } 
    }  
   }  
  }  
 } 
}  
catch (Exception)  
{  
}
finally  
{  
  if (reader != null) reader.Close();  
}
```

The above works great if i have a xml like this:
    
    
        1.0.0.0
        https://google.com/files/Program1.exe

But if i wanted to add a second winforms app, the above would fail, and its silly adding more than one update xml file for each winforms app I make.

I know it is something to do with the element.Nodetype part of the code snippet that fails, as its looking for a string that is inside a different  <>, i have tried a few things but can't seem to get it to detect the string.

Also if you think their is a better way to write the XML for more than one winforms app please give me some examples.

I know it is a bad idea to have a EXE on a website, i also know that its not recommended doing this as if lots of people are downloading at once well.... YEAH..... This is just for my mates and myself.

So if someone can please show a way to make this work for more than one file in the XML that would be absoloutly awesome. I have also emailed the creator of this method, but he hasn't been on his own site since like 2007, probably too busy with the stock market.

Comment: Have you tried removing the check for reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text ?  You won't be able to support unknown xml formats (i.e. adding a new node between version and url, but you are totally in control of that.

Comment: I didn't even think of that @Neil however even though if I did remove that, at the moment I only plan on having "url" and "version" inside, so I don't think that is what is causing the issue.